# How to return the single values as an array?

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have a domain-class mapped though mongo:

```
class VoteTuple {

  long userId

  long statementId
}
```

I need to query a mongo collection

```
VoteTuple.find( [ userId:userId ], [ statementId:1, _id:0, userId:0 ] )
```

which returns me documents with the only field `statementId`. How to `project` this query, so that it returns an array of `long`s ?

Comment: Did you try appending `.toArray()` to the end of your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to accomplish that:

```
def arrayOfLongs = VoteTuple.collection.distinct( 'statementId', [ userId:userId ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **findOne** directly. And you have to use the dynamic **collection** property on the domain class. See example below:

```
VoteTuple.collection.findOne( [ userId:userId ], [ statementId:1, _id:0, userId:0 ] )
```